# Using String variable for "for loop" in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

```
public class ForTest{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         String s;
         for(s="ha"; s!="haha"; s=s+"ha"){
            System.out.println(s);
          }
     }
}
```

In my opinion, this code should work which just print "ha", 
Because after one loop, s="ha" would become s="haha" and then it will stop the loop. 
However, it doesn't stop and shows infinite looping.

Could you help me to know what is the reason of it?

Comment: You are using string and String is immutable and you are comparing object.It will always return false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, simply put `ha` + `ha` will not be `==` to `haha`. Use it like this :

```
    for (s = "ha"; (!s.equals("haha")); s = s + "ha") {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

`==` compares if 2 references point to the same object. `equals()` checks if 2 references point to objects with *same* values.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use it like this:

```
public class ForTest{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         String s;
         for(s="ha"; !s.equals("haha"); s=s+"ha"){
            System.out.println(s);
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have need you can do like this.

```
public class ForTest{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         String s;
         for(s="ha"; !s.equals("haha"); s=s+"ha"){
            System.out.println(s);
          }
     }
}
```